# Несхождение лица и числа

Tags: грамматика

> — Ему Пушкин лиру передал, а мы отдувайся.

Мы - это 1 лицо мн. ч., отдувайся - 2 лицо ед. ч. Почему так смешано? Здесь ведь нужно бы использовать грамматическую форму, соответствующую местоимению *мы*.

Answer (score 2):

"Отдувайся" is the imperative form. One of a number of indirect uses of imperative is *the imperative of obligation* ([here](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#482)). It is typically used in the folowing structure:

- [Situation], а [obligation]

One part of such a sentence describes the situation that leads to the necessity of performing an action the speaker considers unpleasant (which is described in the second part). The action one is forced to perform is in imperative then. It usually should be performed  by the first person, and this person would rather avoid it.

For example:

- Он даже будильник не поставил, а мы теперь жди его. ~ He did not even set his alarm clock, and now we should wait for him (which we are not happy about).

Answer (score 1):

Не существует глагольный формы повелительного наклонения, согласованной с первым лицом (себе не приказывают; здесь "мы"), поэтому применяется вариант без попытки согласования и с множественным числом - это не привело бы к упорядочиванию. Домысливается, будто каждому из "нас" приказали: отдувайся.
Альтернативной формой мог бы быть отказ от повелительного наклонения: "а нам (приходится) отдуваться".

**P.S.** Похожий случай сочетания повелительного наклонения с третьим лицом мн.ч.: "а они возьми, да и умри оба".

Comment: Отчего же не существует? *Отдуваемтесь*, но это форма редкая и устаревающая. Дело в другом, в таком употреблении повелительное наклонение вообще ни с чем не согласуется: с *вы* было бы тоже *отдувайся*, а не *отдувайтесь*.

Comment: @NikolayErshov When exactly was that form in use?

Comment: @Shady_arc: all the way along: *пойдёмте, споёмте* etc.

Comment: Ну и существует форма: отдувайтесь. Почему бы её не использовать

Answer (score 0):

Это повелительное наклонение, а в русском императиве нет формы для первого лица (за исключением *побудительной* у некоторых глаголов, типа *идёмте*, *умрёмте* и т.п.).

В данном случае *мы - отдувайся* то же, что *нам отдуваться*.